# Parser for a lazyloading yellowpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've written a script to harvest Name and Phone number from yellowpage Canada under pizza category. The web page doesn't show its full content until scrolled downmost. In my crawler's every cycle, it fetches 40 records. I twitched a little in my loop which I've learnt lately to get the full content. Hope I did it the way it should be.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

Base_url="https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/{0}/pizza/Toronto"
with requests.session() as session:
    page_num=1
    while True:
        response = session.get(Base_url.format(page_num))
        if response.status_code==404:
            break
        tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
        for titles in tree.xpath("//div[@itemprop='itemListElement']"):
            try:
                title = titles.xpath(".//h3[@itemprop='name']/a/text()")[0]
            except IndexError:
                title=""
            try:
                phone= titles.xpath(".//h4[@itemprop='telephone']/text()")[0]
            except IndexError:
                phone=""
            print(title,phone)
        page_num+=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying [PEP8 recommendations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) about naming and formatting,
as well as wrapping the main logic in a `main` function and calling from within a `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard,
the code would become easier to read and possible to import and test:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url_format = "https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/{0}/pizza/Toronto"


def main():
    with requests.session() as session:
        page_num = 1
        while True:
            response = session.get(url_format.format(page_num))
            if response.status_code == 404:
                break
            tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
            for titles in tree.xpath("//div[@itemprop='itemListElement']"):
                try:
                    title = titles.xpath(".//h3[@itemprop='name']/a/text()")[0]
                except IndexError:
                    title = ""
                try:
                    phone = titles.xpath(".//h4[@itemprop='telephone']/text()")[0]
                except IndexError:
                    phone = ""
                print(title, phone)
            page_num += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm not a huge fan of using exceptions in situations that are not really exceptions, like here:

> ```
> try:
>     title = titles.xpath(".//h3[@itemprop='name']/a/text()")[0]
> except IndexError:
>     title = ""
> ```

What if a `titles.xpath(...)` call would raise an `IndexError` due to a bug? It would be inadvertently caught and unnoticed.
Catching `IndexError` here is an indirect way of the real intention,
which is getting the first title if it exists.
It would be better to write the code in a way that expresses the intention directly, for example:

```
for item in tree.xpath("//div[@itemprop='itemListElement']"):
    title = get_first_or_empty(item, ".//h3[@itemprop='name']/a/text()")
    phone = get_first_or_empty(item, ".//h4[@itemprop='telephone']/text()")
    print(title, phone)
```

Where `get_first_or_empty` is:

```
def get_first_or_empty(item, xpath):
    matches = item.xpath(xpath)
    if matches:
        return matches[0]
    return ""
```

Comment: Thanks sir janos, for such a nice suggestion along with a workaround about handling error. It's hard for me to follow PEP8 recommendations cause I write code using sublime. Thanks a ton.

Comment: How does sublime text prevent you from following PEP8? Genuinely curious.

Comment: I'm a big fan of sublime text editor so don't get me wrong. When I use pycharm I can see the warning when i happen to violate PEP8 recommendations but using sublime I don't see that. If my comment hurts you, apology for that. Thanks.

Comment: @SMth80 there's also a `pep8` command line tool, which you can run on your scripts and it will tell you the violations. You can probably hook up Sublime to run `pep8` when you save a file, but that's just a guess, I don't know Sublime.

Comment: Oh. I thought the core concept of `PEP8` suggests a 4-space indent which should be doable in any editor so I was confused how sublime would make that impossible.

Comment: @yuri I wouldn't call the 4-space indentation "core concept". PEP8 has a lot of recommendations, some are concepts, the recommendation to use 4 spaces seems just a tiny bit of PEP8.